# Pillow is not found by Django thouhg it is installed using docker

Tags: python, django, docker, python-imaging-library

Hello I am following this tutorial [tutorial link](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx). Everything is working fine but when i run bellow command it says pillow is not found but pillow already is installed.

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml exec app python manage.py migrate --noinput`

This is the error:

```
employee.Employee.image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
    HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "python -m pip install Pillow".
students.Student.image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
    HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "python -m pip install Pillow".
```

Then i again try to install using bellow command

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml exec app python -m pip install Pillow
```

And it says pillow is Pillow is already installed

```
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (6.2.1)
```

Here is my docker file

```
###########
# BUILDER #
###########

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine as builder

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev zlib-dev jpeg-dev musl-dev


# lint
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install Pillow
COPY . .


# install dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels -r requirements.txt


#########
# FINAL #
#########

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine

# create directory for the app user
RUN mkdir -p /home/app

# create the app user
RUN addgroup -S app && adduser -S app -G app

# create the appropriate directories
ENV HOME=/home/app
ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/staticfiles
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/mediafiles
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# install dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add libpq
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*

# copy entrypoint-prod.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.prod.sh $APP_HOME

# copy project
COPY . $APP_HOME

# chown all the files to the app user
RUN chown -R app:app $APP_HOME

# change to the app user
USER app

# run entrypoint.prod.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/app/web/entrypoint.prod.sh"]
```

Please Help me .

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use "pillow"  starting from lowercase p.

Answer (score 1):

Add this two lines under the `FINAL` section, just below the `RUN apk update && apk add libpq`

```
# install pillow dependencies
RUN apk add --no-cache jpeg-dev zlib-dev
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps build-base linux-headers
```

This is happening because the `BUILDER` removes the dependencies required for `Pillow` after creating the image. In the `FINAL` image, `Pillow` is available, but its required dependencies are not.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the same problem.
Adding these dependencies to the FINAL section resolved this issue

```
# install pillow dependencies
RUN apk add --no-cache jpeg-dev zlib-dev \
    fribidi-dev \
    harfbuzz-dev \
    lcms2-dev \
    openjpeg-dev \
    tcl-dev \
    tiff-dev \
    tk-dev
```